# Writing exception to parcel java.lang.SecurityException: com.android.phone from uid 10142 not allowed to perform OP_READ_PHONE_STATE

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions, android-scrollview, runtime-permissions

While scrolling and jump onto one fragment to another, my logcat shown this error and my app crashed and restart. Please suggest me any solution regarding this?

Comment: show what you have done and logcat also

Comment: Looks like you are missing READ_PHONE_STATE permission. Your log cat will give exact answer what is missing. If you app tarketSDK is M+ then you need to have runtime permission for READ_PHONE_STATE

Comment: Did you check for runtime permissions for read_phone_state?

Comment: I have implemented gridview using picasso load image while scrolling that perform OP_READ_PHONE_STATE error showing and getting restart my app or getting crashed.

Answer (score 0):

Add in `Manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

In activity page

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);

    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
    } else {
        //TODO
    }
```

Permissions Result

```
 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                  //Do here
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "The app was not allowed to write to your storage.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

For more details, please refer the following link

http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow

Comment: appreciate your answer but sir may I ask you that my app marshmallow versions app getting issues like camera not open, current location So Do I need to set this runtime permission code like @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.MARSHMALLOW) and just like above code for read phone state?